# What is the efficient data structure for the finding the minimum and maximum within a (sorted) associated range?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

example:

```
range - 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
values- 81 21 55 23 45 78 98 69 42 10 33
```

If Data Structure is Array, then the time complexity is `O(n)` where n is the difference between the querying range.

Can Trees provide `O(log n)`? or Is there any better data structure to model this?

Some of the Characteristics of the data.

1. Continuous range values without missing data
2. Can have negative values. So the querying can also be *-10 to 10*
3. Space complexity is can be ignored if better time complexity can be achieved

*Thanks*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Answer (score 1):

Segment Trees are the ones that you want to use. Although it takes about `4*n` (when using a fully binary tree) nodes to construct the segment tree, it is more efficient for querying. A query in a range will be of the order of `log(n)` or the height of the tree. Learn more about segment trees [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051).